Issue with calling Knitro
I use pyomo to formulate my problem and then use ampl to call knitro to solve my problem, as show in code below:
self.solver_pyo = pyo.SolverFactory(modules.find(“Knitro”), solve_io = “nl”)

My program contains 3 processes to solve three different problem simultaneously, with two of them successfully returning local optimal solution, while the third one reports the following errors:
ERROR: Solver (asl) returned non-zero return code (-11)
ERROR: See the solver log above for diagnostic information

I have checked the document of Knitro, it didn’t explain return code (-11).
I wonder if anyone could explain it why it didn’t work. Because I have solved the same problem except a few parameters for numbers of iterations, they worked well. So is it due to the solver is running out of memory ?
